# Access SOAP webservice with ServiceStack

Tags: web-services, soap, servicestack

I'm creating my client/server application intercommunication with ServiceStack, and is working great, but I need also to access an external SOAP web service.

I tried to use the `Soap12ServiceClient` to access it, but I couldn't find any example, and then I went the add service reference WCF way that actually worked, but creating a ton of code.

Is it possible to use `Soap12ServiceClient` in the same easy way I use `JsonServiceClient` to send a message/request and receive the message/response? If so, can you help or point me to a sample?

Comment: Old question but I was interested in doing the same thing -- use ServiceStack's SOAP client to call an external SOAP endpoint instead of having to use Visual Studio's bloated, generated proxies.  After a little trial and error, I noticed that ServiceStack's Soap11ServiceClient and Soap12ServiceClient have hard-coded endpoints of "/Soap11" and "/Soap12".  So, unfortunately, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're stuck as all of [ServiceStack's C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) implement the same `IServiceClient` so they can be used in the same way. Here is an example of all of ServiceStack's built-in C# Service Clients [calling the same Hello World service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/HelloWorldServiceClientTests.cs):

```
[TestFixture]
public class HelloWorldServiceClientTests
{
    public static IEnumerable ServiceClients
    {
        get
        {
            return new IServiceClient[] {
                new JsonServiceClient(Config.ServiceStackBaseUri),
                new JsvServiceClient(Config.ServiceStackBaseUri),
                new XmlServiceClient(Config.ServiceStackBaseUri),
                new Soap11ServiceClient(Config.ServiceStackBaseUri),
                new Soap12ServiceClient(Config.ServiceStackBaseUri)
            };
        }
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource("ServiceClients")]
    public void HelloWorld_with_Sync_ServiceClients(IServiceClient client)
    {
        var response = client.Send<HelloResponse>(new Hello { Name = "World!" });

        Assert.That(response.Result, Is.EqualTo("Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

Although SOAP works similar to any other C# client, it's un-common to use it in this way because if you're able to use a generic C# SOAP service client you're also likely able to use any of the other service clients which are all faster, more resilient and more versionable than SOAP - which has effectively has no redeeming quality over the other formats other than its ability to generate client proxies which you said you don't want to do anyway.

If you're undecided which endpoint or format you should use I [recommend reading my Interview on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) which discusses the disadvantages of SOAP and the benefits of using the other formats.

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood my questions (or maybe I wrote it badly). I'm writing my client and my server, and using ServiceStack on both ends, accessing data with JsonServiceClient, and this works perfectly.
But my server (that retrieves data from a db) must also retrieve data from another web service, not mine, not ServiceStack powered, that I can't modify, a SOAP one, on another server.
So my question is: can I use Soap12ServiceClient to access that server?

Comment: Or better: using ServiceStack on both ends I can get my data with 2 lines of code... if I use just the client (because I have no control of the SOAP server), can I do it in a cleaner way than using "Add service reference"?

Comment: If you're calling an External SOAP service this has nothing to do with ServiceStack so you can't use ServiceStack's generic Service Clients. So you should just do whatever the external service provider suggests.

Comment: The provider just gives the wsdl... I did it easily with the "Add service reference" of visual studio. I was just hoping that the client components of ServiceStack would give the possibility to use also an external SOAP service.
Thanks!