# Servicestack - injecting a SOAP web service

Tags: web-services, soap, servicestack

I would like to call a third-party SOAP web service from within my ServiceStack project ( I have used the default servicestack project layout: [image].

Now, I would like to create a normal Request DTO class (in the servicestack.models projrct). This request is then handled in the ServiceStack.Interfaces project. When handling this request, I would like to call a third party soap service& apply some logic and return a custom response DTO.

However, I am getting stuck in trying to call the relevant SOAP service from the Servicestack.Interfaces project.

**Try Number 1:**
I have tried adding the SOAP service reference to the ServiceStack.Interface (by 'Add Reference...'). However, when trying to call the SOAP Service (from within the ServiceStack.Interfaces project), I get an error message saying 'no endpoint defined/found for this SOAP webservice'.

**Try Number 2:**
I have tried adding the SOAP service reference to the ServiceStack main project.  However,now I am stuck on trying to inject this service so I can call it from the ServiceStack.Interfaces project.

Any help is appreciated,
Mark

Comment: So do you want to create a new endpoint (hosted by your code) that calls some external 3rd party SOAP web service?

Comment: Yes that's right. I want to create a new endpoint (hosted by my own code) that calls another 3rd party soap web service .

Comment: Ok.  You mentioned a few times about calling code "from the ServiceStack.Interfaces" project.  Does that mean you've forked ServiceStack from github and you're adding your code to the ServiceStack.Interfaces project?  Or are you simply trying to call a SOAP web service using a ServiceStack class?

Comment: Simply trying to call a soap service using a servicestack class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issues, I got it working by adding the Soap Service endpoint configuration to the main project's configuration file. After that I was able to query the SOAP service from the WebApplication.ServiceInterface project.

Answer (score 1):

[From this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421585/access-soap-webservice-with-servicestack#comment21810540_15421786), I don't think you'll be able to use a ServiceStack client to access the third party SOAP service (unless, of course, they've built the service using ServiceStack).

In this case, I would simply use some XML serialization and an HTTP POST (followed by some XML deserialization of the response).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Maybe my question was not clear enough , so I have edited it a bit to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: The question seems pretty clear: You want to call a SOAP service from within C# code.  For that, as pointed in my question, you should probably just used XML Serialization and do a POST yourself.  Or, consume the service as recommended by the service's author (do they include .NET bindings?  If it's a .NET ASMX, you could add a reference via Visual Studio, etc...)

Comment: Hi Patrick, they do include .net bindings (wsdl), however, as pointed out in my question if I add the service reference  (route 1) I get no endpoint found error?